# 'allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates' flag not working for 'requireTLS' mode in mongodb running in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, ssl, certificate

According to [Validate Only if a Client Presents a Certificate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#validate-only-if-a-client-presents-a-certificate) in mongodb docs, I run a mongodb container with following mongod.conf configuration file.

```
net:
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/server.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca.pem
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true
```

Here is the command that i used to run the mongodb

```
docker run -d \
        --name mongodb \
        -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root \
        -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword \
        -v /path/to/the/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf \
        -v /path/to/the/server.pem:/etc/ssl/server.pem \
        -v /path/to/the/ca.pem:/etc/ssl/ca.pem \
        -v /path/to/the/client.pem:/etc/ssl/client.pem \
        -p 27017:27017 \
        mongo:4.4.26 --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Then I tried to connect with the mongodb with `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT` username and password. But its showing error with following massage:

```
root@2b95c9e5d8a8:/# mongo admin -u root -p rootpassword
MongoDB shell version v4.4.26
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

From docker log:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-12-28T11:23:29.777+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"The server is configured to only allow SSL connections"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:39754","connectionId":1}}
```

So it needs tls based authentication. But according to mongodb docs

```
A mongod / mongos running with these settings allows connection from:

- Clients that do not present a certificate.

- Clients that present a valid certificate.

All connections, including those that have not presented certificates, are encrypted using TLS/SSL.
```

So as I set `allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates` to true, It should let me connect also encrypt with TLS.But it's not. Is the flag working properly? Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the CA certificate on the client side. Try

```
mongo admin -u root -p rootpassword --tlsCAFile=/path/to/the/ca.pem
```

It may also work with

```
mongo admin -u root -p rootpassword --tlsUseSystemCA
```

or

```
mongo admin -u root -p rootpassword --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates
```

Just a note, as the name implies `/path/to/the/client.pem` is a **client** certificate, you don't need this on the MongoDB **server** side.

And `CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca.pem` is only needed if you plan to connect with a client certificate - which does not seem to be the case.

Some more notes:

There is no "tls based authentication". In general, a certificate (used in MongoDB) may provide three functions:

- Provide keys to encrypt the connection with TLS/SSL. This is done by the **server** certificate and works also with an invalid certificate.
- Guaranties that the server machine is really the machine you intend to connect to (also done by **server** certificate)
- Authenticate a client - instead of using username/password. Obviously this is done be a **client** certificate.

In a Shared Cluster and/or Replica Set, the certificates can be also used to authenticate the internal cluster/replicaSet members. Technically, this is identical to "authenticate a client"

Comment: So the connection will be TLS encrypted even if I don't provide any `CAFile` for this configuration?

Comment: Yes, a connection established with an invalid certificate (or a certificate which is not validated at all) is encrypted with TLS. But as stated in my answer, it must be permitted by according options. It is stated in multiple pages, e.g. [tlsAllowInvalidCertificates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/options/#std-option-mongosh.--tlsAllowInvalidCertificates): "*an invalid certificate is only sufficient to establish a TLS / SSL connection...*"

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help. I have another question. Is it possible, If I want to make TLS encrypted connection but without providing `CAFile` and not using `--tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` flag ? In `preferTLS` mode I can use SCRAM(password based) authentication, but the connection is not TLS encrypted I think. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think so. Either you validate the certificate - then you need the CA - or you allow invalid certificate - then you need to specify. And I think you need to add `--tls` option when TLS is not enforced.